# MYSQL Very strange select behavior

Tags: mysql, select, behavior

I have got a Mysql (5.1.58-1ubuntu1) 'users' table (*InnoDB* storage engine, *utf8 general ci* collation) with 3 fields (for simplicity) :

- *id* : int (primary key)
- *username* : varchar(255) - utf8_general_ci
- *password* : varchar(255) - utf8_general_ci

In this table there are only two records (always for simplicity):

```
id| username | password
-----------------------
1 | myuser   | custom1
2 | myuser2  | custom2
```

So, if i run this query

```
 select * from users where username = 0 and password = 0
```

mysql return me all records.

On the contrary , if i run the query below

```
select * from users where username = '0' and password = '0'
```

MySql return me an empty set.

For my opinion this behavior is very strange and it seems a Hard Bug.

Someone has any explanations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug. You can only compare values of the same types, so MySQL silently converts your text 'myuser' to an integer with the value of 0.

Comment: Well, that's the way MySQL does conversions. It you have an integer column and try to insert text in it, it will convert it to 0. The same thing will happen for example for a date, or if you try to insert text outside of the column's limits, it will silently truncate it.

Comment: @alesdario, because MySQL has a set of type conversion rules (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) and treats the values comparable after casting.